# How to make my update query work using my code below

Tags: php, sql, laravel, forms, insert

I am setting up an update profile page using php and a bit of laravel. I have an if check that checks if the form is submitted and I have an update query.

The update query only works outside of the if statement and I have no idea why. If I put in inside of the if statement it doesnt do anything. I have checked if all the names are the same as in my sql database and they are all correct.

```
    <form class="form" id="registrationForm">
          <div class="form-group">

            <div class="col-xs-6">
              <label for="first_name">
                <h4>Voornaam</h4></label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="voornaam" id="first_name" placeholder="<?= $user->voornaam; ?>" title="enter your first name if any.">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">

              <div class="col-xs-6">
                <label for="last_name">
                  <h4>Achternaam</h4></label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="achternaam" id="last_name" placeholder="<?= $user->achternaam; ?>" title="enter your last name if any.">
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">

                <div class="col-xs-6">
                  <label for="phone">
                    <h4>Gebruikersnaam</h4></label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="gebruikersnaam" id="username" placeholder="<?= $user->gebruikersnaam; ?>" title="enter your phone number if any.">
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <label for="mobile">
                      <h4>Telefoon nummer</h4></label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="telefoonnummer" id="mobile" placeholder="<?= $user->telefoonnummer; ?>" title="enter your mobile number if any.">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">

                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                      <label for="email">
                        <h4>Email</h4></label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="<?= $user->email; ?>" title="enter your email.">
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                      <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <br>
                        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-success" type="submit" name="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></i> Sla op</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-lg" type="reset" name="resetww"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-repeat"></i> Verander wachtwoord</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </form>

                  <?php

                  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

                    $voornaam = $_POST['voornaam'];
                    $achternaam = $_POST['achternaam'];
                    $gebruikersnaam = $_POST['gebruikersnaam'];
                    $telefoonnummer = $_POST['telefoonnummer'];
                    $email = $_POST['email'];
                    App\User::where('klant_id', 1)->update(['gebruikersnaam' => $gebruikersnaam, 'voornaam' => $voornaam, 'achternaam' => $achternaam, 'email' => $email ,'telefoonnummer' => $telefoonnummer]);
                  }

                   ?>
```

I want my database to be updated

Comment: Sidenote; try to use Laravel as the MVC framework it is. You shouldn't be doing your `update()` logic in the view; that's what controllers are for.

Comment: Can you show me an example of an controller who handles forms and what i have to put in my form action to get to that controller please.

Comment: That's quite broad... You need to define a route to handle the `POST`, connect it to a `Controller`, define a method, etc etc. I'd suggest reading up on how Laravel works from the start.

Comment: You wouldn't expect it but thats actualy very helpfull.

Comment: Well that's good; I was trying to be helpful, but there's too much going on here to write an answer in my opinion (SO has a close reason of "Too broad", which providing an answer to that comment would fall under). Try to implement the Laravel methodology, and if you have a more specific issue, feel free to edit this question with any new information.

Answer (score 0):

Put the tag in your form, the PHP is trying to find de POST but you are not sending it.

> method="POST"

Comment: I have tried that but than i get this : MethodNotAllowedHttpException
The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.

Answer (score 0):

First of all mention form method as below and use csrf token

@csrf

Why u can't use controller to complete this work
First of all use controller, Then make a method to update information

```
public function update_user(Request $request){
      if ($request->isMethod('post')) {
            $data = $request->all();
            User = new User();
            $voornaam = $_POST['voornaam'];
            $achternaam = $data['achternaam'];
            $gebruikersnaam = $data['gebruikersnaam'];
            $telefoonnummer = $data['telefoonnummer'];
            $email = $data['email'];enter code here
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I give the $request parametes when i call the function in my web.php(route)?